# How can I give chrome extensions access on specific sites (and all subdomains)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

How can I give chrome extensions access on specific sites (and all subdomains)? For example, if I enter youtube.com in the "allowed sites" list, the extension only works on youtube.com but no subdomains. How can I allow it on all YouTube pages?

[Allowed sites list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zH1L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: *://*.youtube.com/*